# Using SPI_SETSCREENSAVESECURE doesn't enable password protection for the Windows screensaver

Tags: vb.net, winapi, windows-7, windows-screensaver

When I run the following line of code, my screensaver's password protection isn't enabled. I've also checked the registry key that used to control password protection and it doesn't get toggled either.

```
    If SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVESECURE, 1, nullVar, SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE) = 0 Then
        Throw New WindowsDotHException(ErrorToString(Err.LastDllError()) & " (Error number " & Err.LastDllError & ")")
    End If
```

Context:

WindosDotHException is my way of handling error codes from SystemParametersInfo.

```
    ' Signatures for unmanaged calls
<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SystemParametersInfo(uAction As Integer, uParam As Integer, ByRef lpvParam As Integer, flags As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SystemParametersInfo(uAction As Integer, uParam As Integer, ByRef lpvParam As Boolean, flags As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function PostMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, wMsg As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function OpenDesktop(hDesktop As String, Flags As Integer, Inherit As Boolean, DesiredAccess As UInteger) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function CloseDesktop(hDesktop As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function EnumDesktopWindows(hDesktop As IntPtr, callback As EnumDesktopWindowsProc, lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function IsWindowVisible(hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function

' Callbacks
Private Delegate Function EnumDesktopWindowsProc(hDesktop As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean

' Constants
Private Const SPI_GETSCREENSAVERACTIVE As Integer = 16
Private Const SPI_SETSCREENSAVERACTIVE As Integer = 17
Private Const SPI_GETSCREENSAVERTIMEOUT As Integer = 14
Private Const SPI_SETSCREENSAVERTIMEOUT As Integer = 15
Private Const SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING As Integer = 114
Private Const SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE As Integer = 2
Private Const SPI_SETSCREENSAVESECURE As Integer = 119

Private Const DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS As UInteger = &H80
Private Const DESKTOP_READOBJECTS As UInteger = &H1
Private Const WM_CLOSE As Integer = 16
```

Operating system: Windows 7 32-bit edition

Language: VB .Net

Things I've tried:

- Rebooting the computer
- logging off and logging back on after running the code

What can I do to enable password protection in Windows 7?

Comment: What is the error code the function is setting? You don't know the text of the exception message.

Comment: What do you mean by "What is the error code the function is setting"?

Comment: Ooops, I meant "You don't **show** the text of the exception message."  You're throwing a `WindowsDotHException` if the call to the `SystemParametersInfo` function fails, and that exception contains the `Err.LastDllError` code that is set by the Win32 function, but you don't show us what that exception message is.

Comment: There's no error message. The code just fails silently.